# Cumulative sum in a table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have a table with 3 columns. Name, Mark and School_day. I want to take day by day cumulative marks for 30 days. I have tried below.

```
select sum(Mark), Name from Table1
where School_day between '2020-06-15'::date -29 and '2020-06-15'::date
group by Name
```

But I want to run this for a date period instead of running it daily.

I have tried below, but it does not give correct figures.

```
select sum(Mark), Name, School_day from Table1
where between School_day-29 and School_day
group by Name, School_day
order by School_day
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let me know if you have questions about how it works.

```
select Name, School_day, 
       sum(Mark) over (partition by Name 
                           order by School_day)
  from Table1
 where now() - School_day < interval '29 days'
 order by Name, School_day;
```